# Black shading appears in faces

Tags: faces

I'm Modelling a car in which i'm getting a black shading while in rendered mode.
i've tried deleting the faces but still im getting those black shades.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it doesn't look like a normal problem, maybe you've smoothed in the left panel and enabled the auto-smooth option in the Properties panel > Data > Normals. So either increase or decrease the angle value, it determines the angle under which the smoothing happens, or simply deactivate smooth shading? It depends on what you want actually

Comment: ThankYou..I'll try that@moonboots

Answer (score 2):

Try the following solutions

1. **Maybe just because of the Smooth Shading applied for a low poly 3D model:** Your model is currently at a low poly stage so change it into high res model or remove smooth shading until you add in more details to the model(maybe at least till you add subsurfs).
2. **Normals Issue:** Try recalculating the normals -> enter edit mode and select all then press Ctrl+N key
3. **Duplicate Vertices or edges issue:** Enter into edit mode and select all, then press W key and click on Remove doubles